# How to iterate over a column and assign value based on another column without a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to efficiently assign a value to a column, based on another column, but without a for loop as this takes too long.

I'm doing something like this: If the reference column value is greater than a certain random number, I assign 1 to the new column. Otherwise, assign 0. Can't figure out the best way to do this without a loop. I tried `dplyr` and `case_when`, but that wasn't iterating over each row.

Thanks!

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if (data$value[i] > runif(1, 0, 1.7)) {
     temp$newValue[i] <- 1
  } else{
     temp$newValue[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `temp$newValue <- +(data$value > runif(nrow(data), 0, 1.7))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
c0=data.frame(c(1,4,6,3,7,3),c(2,8,2,4,9,4))
names(c0)=c("A","B")

c0$C=ifelse(c0[,"A"]>runif(1,0,1.7),1,0)
c0
```

I'm not so sure if I understand you well. Please comment if I have any misunderstanding.

```
A
<dbl>
B
<dbl>
C
<dbl>
1   2   0       
4   8   1       
6   2   1       
3   4   1       
7   9   1       
3   4   1       
6 rows
```

Here is how I use A to generate C

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

**DATA**:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  refcol = rnorm(10)
)

randvalue <- 0
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
df$newcol <- ifelse(df$refcol > randvalue, 1, 0)
```

**RESULT**:

```
df
       refcol newcol
1   0.2352207      1
2  -0.3307359      0
3  -0.3116238      0
4  -2.3023457      0
5  -0.1708760      0
6   0.1402782      1
7  -1.4974267      0
8  -1.0101884      0
9  -0.9484756      0
10 -0.4939622      0
```